# How do you fit one equation into a single line of java code

Tags: java

I'm new to java so sorry if it's a silly question.
So I am generating 6 random numbers with this code:

```
  int  x1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
  int  y1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
  
  int  x2 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
  int  y2 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
  
  int  x3 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
  int  y3 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
```

The goal is to calculate the distances the points are from each other. with this equation √(x2-x1)^2+(Y2-y1)^2  so (like x1 to x2) x2 to x3 and finally x3 to x1

now should I split it up or is it possible to use one line of code using something like

Math.sqrt()?

Comment: Sure, you can use one line... New lines are entirely optional in Java. But why sacrifice readability?

Comment: It might make sense to use `Path2D.Double` and use the distance functions from `Point2D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more elegant to create a method to encapsulate that behavior.

```
public double distanceBetweenPoints(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2));
}
```

Now you can call that method on whichever values you wish to compute.

```
double firstDistances = distanceBetweenPoints(x1, x2, y1, y2);
double secondDistances = distanceBetweenPoints(x2, x3, y2, y3);

// Transitive property at work here - you may want to double-check that this is correct    
double totalDistanceBetweenPoints = secondDistances-firstDistances;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible (and would make the most sense) in one line.

```
double dist = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2);
```

If you want multiple variables for different distances, you will need different statements.

Comment: I don't think OP wants separate variables

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage for this code it is possible to split it into multiple lines or leave it as one. Because you are relatively new I would suggest splitting the code to make it easier to read even if you condense the code in the future. For example the split version of the code would look something like this.

```
int  x1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
int  y1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;

int  x2 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;
int  y2 = rand.nextInt(20) + 5;

int  xcalc = Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2);
int  ycalc = Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2);
int  dist = Math.sqrt(xcalc + ycalc);
```